# Why is my Android service taking so long to start?

Tags: android, service

I am using a service to manage my app's error logging. I am starting it in the Application object, with the code shown below.

```
public void onCreate() {
  super.onCreate();
  Log.d(TAG, "Starting ErrorHandlingService");
  startService(ErrorHandlingService.createIntent(this));
}
```

I am loading several DBs when the app boots (in the main activity's onCreate) and want to be able to log any errors associated with that. However, for some reason, it is taking 15 seconds or more for my service to start (the time between calling startService and the service's onCreate running), and I obviously don't want to delay the app boot time that much.

Is there any reason why the service should take so long to start and is there anything that I can do about it?

Comment: So you are saying it takes 15sec between startService till onCreate of the service? Have you trying running profiling of the startup sequence? Relying on log for timing won't be accurate.

Comment: Have you tried starting the service from the manifest itself?